# "User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: media in drupal_get_filename()"

Tags: 8, media

What does this error message mean? How can I fix it?

> User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: media in drupal_get_filename() (line 268 of core/includes/bootstrap.inc).
> drupal_get_filename('theme', 'media') (Line: 291)
> drupal_get_path('theme', 'media') (Line: 394)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->drupalGetPath('theme', 'media') (Line: 85)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension('media') (Line: 87)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->getLibraryDefinitions('media') (Line: 66)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->resolveCacheMiss('media') (Line: 149)
> Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheCollector->get('media') (Line: 44)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibrariesByExtension('media') (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName('media', 'form') (Line: 54)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->doGetDependencies(Array, Array) (Line: 56)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->doGetDependencies(Array) (Line: 31)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->getLibrariesWithDependencies(Array) (Line: 104)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getLibrariesToLoad(Object) (Line: 116)
> Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getCssAssets(Object, ) (Line: 291)
> Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAssetLibraries(Object, Array) (Line: 161)
> Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAttachments(Object) (Line: 45)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HtmlResponseSubscriber->onRespond(Object, 'kernel.response', Object)  call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.response', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.response', Object) (Line: 191)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 173)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Comment: I got this from an incorrect path from an attach_library('was-wrong/libname') call in a twig file.

Comment: I had a similar error when trying to add or edit an image media. I cleared my browser caching and it helped. Can't explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue. Resolved with:

- search THEME-NAME string in themes folder
- remove reference to the useless theme

In my case, I was having

```
User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: pxrflx in drupal_get_filename()
```

This warning disappeard once I removed

```
libraries:
  - pxrflx/global-styling
```

from the **a_differnt_theme_from_pxrflx.yml** file

Comment: Thanks, this helped lead me to the apparent cause in my case, which wasn't a reference to the other theme in the *.info.yml or *.libraries.yml files, but related (references in templates to `{{ attach_library('problem_theme/some_library') }}`)

Answer (score 1):

This warning generally occurs if Drupal can't find the folder of the related module or theme. There is a manual page on how to get rid of this error: [How to fix "The following module is missing from the file system..." warning messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215).

Looking at the date of the question, there is a big chance this is happening because of version conflict between the [*Media entity*](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) module and source provider modules. If the installed version of the *Media entity* module is 1.x, then your core media module is not installed. If you are using the 2.x version of the media source provider modules like the [*Media entity video*](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_video) module or the [*Video Embed Field*](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module, they are probably looking for the core *Media* module.

If you're building a new site, you should start over with the core Media module. If you're upgrading your existing site, you should follow the upgrade path. Instructions for both are given on the [*Media entity*](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) project page.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to why this problem exists is when a module or theme is installed, but doesn't enable all the required dependencies it needs to operate. That's often what throws an error like this.

The error can be a bit confusing, since it lists a theme as missing, when the problem could lie with a missing or yet-to-be-enabled module.

In this particular case, you could probably run `drush pm:enable media` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Used this reference https://www.drupal.org/node/2940438 and found the deprecated functions and this fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).